# emmeans adds Days together

Tags: r, emmeans, posthoc

I want to do a posthoc / pairwise comparison with `emmeans`. My model says, as soon as I add `Day` as an explanatory variable, it gets significant. But when I do posthoc analyses, it gets weird and I get the following result:
For some reasons, R gives me 5.1 as Day, in my minimal reproducible example it is 5.33.

```r
Day emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL .group
5.1   14.2 0.993 4.36     11.5     16.9  A
```

For some context: Over two weeks, i incubated different Treeorgans of two tree species and took samples every so often (Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 5, Day 8, etc) and measured various things with these samples. Unfortunately, because of some technical issues, some days are not the same for both species, e.g., Experiment of Species 1 ends after 14 days; for Species 2, it ends after 16 days.
Could this maybe be the issue ? How do I fix it? (Day is continuous)

Here is an example of how my dataset looks like

```r
ID  Species         Organ   TreeNR  Day Result
#1  Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree1   0   30.7
#2  Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree1   0   10.3
#3  Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree2   0   20.0
#4  Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree2   0   10.0
#5  Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree1   1   16.4
#6  Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree1   1   -3.7
#7  Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree2   1   15.0
#8  Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree2   1   -6.0
#9  Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree1   14  17.3
#10 Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree1   14  13.0
#11 Fagus sylvatica Roots   Tree2   14  12.0
#12 Fagus sylvatica Leaves  Tree2   14  13.0
#13 Picea abies Roots   Tree1   0   7.9
#14 Picea abies Leaves  Tree1   0   7.2
#15 Picea abies Roots   Tree2   0   10.0
#16 Picea abies Leaves  Tree2   0   12.0
#17 Picea abies Roots   Tree1   1   30.4
#18 Picea abies Leaves  Tree1   1   7.5
#19 Picea abies Roots   Tree2   1   12.0
#20 Picea abies Leaves  Tree2   1   13.0
#21 Picea abies Roots   Tree1   16  17.8
#22 Picea abies Leaves  Tree1   16  18.5
#23 Picea abies Roots   Tree2   16  20.0
#24 Picea abies Leaves  Tree2   16  21.0
```

Here is the model in question:

```r
model4 <- lmer((D14C_sugar) ~  Species + Organ + Day + (1|TreeNR), REML = FALSE, data = Sol)

if(requireNamespace("multcomp")) {
  model4_ph <-lmer((D14C_sugar) ~  Species + Organ + Day + (1|TreeNR), REML = T, data = Sol)
  model4_ph.emm <- emmeans (model4_ph, ~ Day) 
  multcomp::cld(model4_ph.emm, alpha = 0.05, Letters = LETTERS)
}
```

summary of model

````r
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: (Result) ~ Species + Organ + Day + (1 | TreeNR)
   Data: Sol

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1075.8   1096.7   -530.9   1061.8      138 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7659 -0.5320  0.0367  0.5097  3.4541 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 TreeNR   (Intercept)  0.7387  0.8595  
 Residual             88.0164  9.3817  
Number of obs: 145, groups:  TreeNR, 5
```r
````

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please? At least, can we see the output of `summary()` of your model?  Is `Day` a continuous (numeric) or categorical (factor) predictor?

Comment: Yes, of course! Sorry for not including it right away. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Day is a numeric (thus continuous) variable. Therefore emmeans will average its value. To perform comparisons at specific days, you can use the `at` argument of the `emmeans` function.

```
model4_ph.emm <- emmeans(model4_ph, ~ Day, at=list(Day=c(0, 1))
contrast(model4_ph.emm, "tukey")
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thank you very much ! 
Regarding your second line code: As far as I know, cld of the multcomp package includes tukey. But I am happy to be corrected if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: Hi @ChristinL., both `multcomp::cld` and `emmeans::contrast` are fine to use but they provide slightly different information. I am more used to `contrast` but there is no issue in usind `cld`. If the answer solved your problem, it would be great if you could tick the checkmark on its left side :)

Comment: The **multcomp** method uses by default what is the `"mvt"` correction in **emmeans**. And note that those use a ranomized algorithm so the P values would be slightly different if you run it again.